# Is it better to use BTreeMap or HashMap with short String keys?

Tags: string, performance, rust, hash, b-tree

From a performance perspective, is it better to use String-keyed BTreeMap or String-keyed  HashMap?
In my application, the string keys may be up to 15-chars long.

Comment: Only one possible answer to that: benchmark with your data and your usage pattern (i.e. mostly lookup, or mostly modifications, or mostly insertions but no removals, or…)

Comment: For reliable benchmarks, you can use [`criterion`](https://bheisler.github.io/criterion.rs/book/index.html) which takes care of common timing pitfalls for you.

Comment: If you use a hashmap, consider replacing the default hasher. And also consider using small-string optimization.

Comment: I suspected it. Thanks for your advices.